# Accessing dictionaries with field names

Tags: python, pickle

I have an unpickle function which returns a dict as:

```
def unpickle(file):
with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
    dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
return dict
```

and a function which reads pickled object with fieldnames (Don't know if this is the correct definiton):

```
def do_sth():
    all_data = unpickle('mypickle.pickle')
    image_filenames = all_data["Filenames"]
    conditions = all_data["Labels"]
```

I have two lists as `Filenames = ['001.png','002.png']` and `Labels = ['0','1']` for brevity, that I need to pickle and save under `mypickle.pickle` so I can call them under the `do_sth` function. Till now what I did is:

```
data = [Filenames,Labels]
with open("mypickle.pickle", "wb") as f:
pickle.dump(data, f)
```

and

```
data = dict(zip(file_paths, labels))
with open("mypickle.pickle", "wb") as f:
pickle.dump(data, f)
```

But I'm getting `KeyError :'Filenames'`. Which structure shall I use to save these 2 lists so they may work properly.
Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think `pickle.load` should be returning your `data` object as a dictionary? It was given to `dump` as a list and that's how it is returned by `load`. The [simplest example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#examples) returns a `dict` only because that is what is dumped.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I also saved it as a dict (just added to the end of the question) and still have a `KeyError`. The underline is what should be the proper format to pickle these two lists so after dumping, `all_data=["Filenames"]` would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your function to this

```
def do_sth():
    all_data = unpickle('mypickle.pickle')     
    image_filenames = all_data[0]    
    conditions = all_data[1]
```

**Explanation**

You saved pickle as list. When you load the pickle it is still a list.

**or**

Actually save it as a dict

```
data = {"Filenames": Filenames, "Labels": Labels}
with open("mypickle.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(data,  f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification. But I need to know how should I save these two lists so I can call them as defined in the function.

Comment: I guess this is it. I didn't knew if I could save dicts this way. Thanks.

Comment: You should look at the examples in the docs which do exactly this.